# Better place to save images in device

Tags: android

Lets say, i am creating a news app and also fetching the images from server.
Which is best place to save those images? in Cache Directory or external directory? since those images might be 500kb or sometimes even 1 MB or less.. How to manage those images since those files are app specific and user can read news containing images in offline too..
Currently i am saving in internal cache directory by creating another folder inside cache directory. If i save it in SD Card then wont it create problem for the phone or tablet which don't have Memory Card?

Any Alternative best way?﻿

Comment: store images in external storage directory. In some cases its sd card. in other cases its external storage on the phone memory

Comment: Thanks for ur reply raghu.. Relying on external storage is a best practice?

Comment: i prefer external storage for  large amoutn of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader lib to loading images , it do a lot of work for you. To cache images you on sdcard just needed to properly set up ImageLoaderConfiguration and DisplayImageOptions fields.

Comment: Thank you andrey.. as i said, its a news app.. i need to insert the image path in sqlite database too.. so will it work properly?

Comment: Once your image was loaded you use DiscCacheUtil.findInCache(imageUri, imageLoader.getDiscCache()) to get this image. In db I suggest to store only image url, after that you can call ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(imageUrl, displayoptions,imageview) method, if image for this url was loaded previously and storied in cache, it take this images from cache,otherwise will load image, store it in cache and display on the screen.